# Updating app on itunesconnect with out original source code, how?

Tags: app-store-connect

So I have an app I created about 2 years ago. And honestly it never sold that well so I trashed the source code on it. Well recently I have taken an interest in updating the app. Can I upload a new version that is not from original source code? Do I just need to name with it with the same bundle identifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to upload your new version on top of the old one, providing (of course) that the version number has been incremented and that the bundle ID is the same for the app.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you I will have to try it here very soon (as soon as I finish the update).